# brew install open-mpi fails

Tags: homebrew, openmpi, ctype

Trying to install `openmpi`, read that:

```
Could not determine if REAL*16 bit-matches C type
```

Ran brew doctor, and it's giving me:

```
Your system is raring to brew
```

#### full output

```
% brew install open-mpi

==> Downloading http://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.6/downloads/openmpi-1.6.
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/open-mpi-1.6.4.tar.bz2
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/1.6.4 --enable-ipv6
checking alignment of Fortran REAL*16... 16
checking for C type matching bit representation of REAL*16... pending
checking if long double == REAL*16... ./configure: line 40736: 15744 Abort trap: 6 
$F77 $FFLAGS conftest_f.f conftest_c.o -o conftest $LDFLAGS $LIBS 1>&5 2>&1
Error!
configure: error: Could not determine if REAL*16 bit-matches C type

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting


brew doctor 
Your system is raring to brew
```

Comment: Which C and Fortran compilers are installed?

Comment: To me this looks like it's trying to use a Fortran compiler and then complaining that it cannot see if the results are compatible with C. Maybe try installing GCC as your compiler for Homebrew instead and try again?

Comment: This behaviour might be intended if Fortran and C object files are used in the same application. But I also suggest installing gcc and gfortran and then try again.

Comment: Waiting for your answers, I tried with an older version of open-mpi, and it works without any problem.
I have already install gcc and gfortran before Open-mpi.

Answer (score 2):

There were some issues with recent gfortran builds in Homebrew. Try reinstalling it with `brew rm gfortran; brew install --fresh gfortran`. If the error persists, head over to the Homebrew GitHub page and report it as a bug: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an issue with the gmp and mpfr bottles, which are dependencies of gfortran and thus open-mpi. Try doing `brew rm gmp mpfr; brew install --build-from-source gmp mpfr open-mpi`

ref: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/19046